# Est-il préférable de répéter « demain » pour plus de clarté, au risque de rendre la phrase redondante?

Tags: formulation, reformulation, style-de-rédaction

Contexte:

Un ami me propose de faire de quoi le lendemain, et moi de lui répondre:

> A. Je déterminerai demain si nous pouvons nous voir (demain) selon mon état d’esprit du moment. J’ai un traitement médical lundi. J’anticipe et redoute ce moment, ce qui me rend anxieux.

À *du moment* est-il possible de substituer *actuel*? Serait-il envisageable de tout simplement s’en passer?

Voici deux autres versions de la phrase en question.

> B. Je déterminerai demain si nous pouvons nous voir (ce jour-là) en fonction de mon état d’esprit actuel. J’anticipe et redoute mon traitement médical de lundi, ce qui me rend anxieux.

> C. Je déterminerai plus tard si nous pouvons nous voir demain en fonction de mon état d’esprit ce jour-là. J’anticipe et redoute mon traitement médical de lundi, ce qui me rend anxieux.

Pourriez-vous me donner des exemples de tournures plus élégantes, plus concises, plus descriptives et peut-être moins redondantes, du moins avec une meilleure mise en rapport des idées.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> J’ai un traitement médical lundi et généralement ça me rend anxieux
> alors ça va dépendre (de comment je me sens/de mon état d'esprit demain) ce qui fait que je
> préfère décider le jour même si on peut se voir ou non.

Une manière parmi tant d'autres...

Comment: Parmi mes propositions (A., B., C.), laquelle serait à privilégier?

Comment: Est-il possible de considérer que la réponse implique implicitement le jour « demain » étant donné que c’était la demande du locuteur?

Comment: Quoi qu’il en soit, en dehors de ce point, je souhaiterais savoir si l’usage des termes « actuel » et « du moment » sont appropriés dans le contexte de la réponse.

Comment: @Antivlad Spontanément je dirais B. Ma réponse est prend pour acquis que la personne suggère le samedi une rencontre pour dimanche, mais oui comme la personne suggère demain je ne vois pas trop le besoin d'inclure demain dans la réponse (on pourrait omettre le mot _demain_ de ma réponse) et ajouter _la veille_ après _anxieux_, par exemple. _Du moment_ appelle souvent un complément (_présent_) et autrement c'est surtout l'époque je crois, et je trouve pas qu'_actuel_ marche quand on parle d'une action dans le futur, je dirais _à ce moment-là_... D'autres réponses/analyses sont possibles...